# Using a Python IDE with OSGeo

Tags: python, osgeo4w, osgeo

I have the latest version of OSGeo4W64 installed on my Windows machine. I find it very convenient to have all the Python modules for QGIS, GDAL and GRASS all in one place. I would like to set up an IDE such as Spyder to work in the OSGeo ecosystem.

According to my understanding, OSGeo and its various modules require several environment variables to be set correctly before Python will work. Simply pointing Spyder to the `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\python.exe` interpreter does not work on its own. Does anyone have experience getting this type of setup to work, either with Spyder or any other IDEs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For working with VSCode as an IDE, I can launch it from within the OSGeo4W shell with

```
> o4w_env
>"C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

and then select the OsGeo4W python interpreter before proceeding. The `o4w_env` command should set all the variables you need. I haven't tested this extensively but can e.g. `import grass` successfully. Spyder should function in a similar fashion.

Comment: This works for me, except that I cannot import grass, I am getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grass'`. Did you use any other settings to get this to work?

Comment: OK, tried again, and it works if you run VS from the grass gis console. That loads all the required environmental variables.